# Unity; Control angle of PhysX joint, while respecting collisions

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have an arm like object with 2 configurable joints sequentially attached to a kinematic base. Each joint is configured to be a revolute joint about a single axis.

Each joint can be moved by the user, problems arise when involving collisions. The desired angle of each joint is set, however if there is an object in the way, the joint will continue to try to move to that target angle which continues to increment regardless of the collision.

If now the joint 2 is moved so that the joint 1 is now able to move to its target angleit would create a snapping action and is undesirable.

In the linked unity package is my attempt to solve this. I am comparing the actual joint angle with the desired angle, and if their difference is beyond a certain threshold then the desired value eases back. This works well for joint1, however there are problems for joint2, even though I've tried to allow for rotation of its parent joint.

I was hoping there might be a different approach to solving this problem. I have tried using a directional 'target angular velocity' instead of setting the desired 'target rotation', however I need the joint to move at a constant speed, and when using 'target angular velocity' this is harder to achieve as gravity (which needs to be kept on) and other problems effect the speed.

Webplayer: http://beinginsight.co.uk/questions/JointAngleProblem/

UnityPackage: http://beinginsight.co.uk/questions/JointAngleProblem/JointAngleProblem.unitypackage

Keys: 
  joint1: Q/A 
  joint2: W/S

I thought this would be a trivial problem, but it seems I have spent an age trying to get it to work correctly.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

PS: As you'll see in the package I've been trying some different methods, all to no avail, here is some code to entice your help;

```
// Restrain pos by actual joint angle; in case of collision
// a is only the smallest/unsigned angle, need signed angle to calculate differnce
//TODO: Been trying different ways to calculate angle, none ideal so far, please help
float a = getAngularPositionQuat(Inputs[i].JointObject, Inputs[i].Quant);   // Compensates for 'initial angle' too

//float a = Quaternion.Angle(getJointRotation(Inputs[i].JointObject), Inputs[i].Quant);

//float a = JointInput.DirectionalAngle( Inputs[i].JointObject.connectedBody.transform.up, 
//                                       Inputs[i].JointObject.transform.up, -Inputs[i].JointObject.connectedBody.transform.forward);


// Find direction of angle with consideration to parent/world rotations
        Vector3 dirr = Inputs[i].JointObject.connectedBody.transform.InverseTransformDirection( Inputs[i].JointObject.gameObject.transform.up);  //localPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set position, rotation, joint angle, or pretty much anything on a rigidbody without using physics commands like addForce then it breaks the physics engine simulation for at least that frame. The best way to do this is to use addForce, or in this case, I believe AddTorque would be appropriate. Just beware of framerate adjustments for the amount of torque added, best to use FixedUpdate for this.